# OpenWRT configuration when router is in bridged mode

Tags: routing, openwrt, bridge

I am planning on putting my Zyxel ADSL modem in bridged mode and use an OpenWRT router instead as the exit point from my local network.

So, what protocol must have the **Wan** interface if the router is bridged mode? I have 3 options:

- Static
- DHCP Client
- Unmanaged

Since my ADSL has a dynamic IP, static surely isn't an option, so I guess DHCP should do it, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: AFAIK bridged mode means, that you as a client have to do PPPoE yourself and you would get public IP?

Comment: Yes, got it after little research although doesn't work yet.

Comment: You answered your own question.  Your IP on the WAN-side is provided by the ISP.  It's a dynamic IP address; therefore, DHCP is the correct answer.  Now, there might be other possibilities or hypothetical options, but that's kind of a broad question here.  You should do some research on your own about what **YOU** want/need before asking others to decide *for you*!